# Cakephp Association Property belongs to Image but also has many images

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am currently trying to solve a problem which I just noticed since the property didn't actually have a main_image allocated to it.

But as soon as I allocated a main image to it. The Related images caused problems.

Property table has a belongsTo relation

```
public $belongsTo = array( 'Image' => array(
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'main_image_id'
        ));
```

and also a hasMany

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Image' => array(
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id'
        )
    );
```

the problem is when I am populating the related images I am receiving multiple errors similar to the below

> Illegal string offset 'id'

my data is like so

```
property(array)
    Image(array)
        id1
        descriptionPainted Brick Design
        imageuploads/properties/3/Amazing-Painted-Brick-Houses-Design.jpeg
        property_id3
        0(array)
            id1
            descriptionPainted Brick Design
            imageuploads/properties/3/Amazing-Painted-Brick-Houses-Design.jpeg
            property_id3
```

and the view was generated like so

```
<div class="related">
    <h3><?php echo __('Related Images'); ?></h3>
    <?php if (!empty($property['Image'])): ?>
    <table cellpadding = "0" cellspacing = "0">
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo __('Id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Description'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Image'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo __('Property Id'); ?></th>
        <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($property['Image'] as $image): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $image['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $image['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $image['image']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $image['property_id']; ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'view', $image['id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'edit', $image['id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'delete', $image['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $image['id'])); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>

    <div class="actions">
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Image'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure if maybe the relations are setup incorrectly or that maybe I would have to include an if to see if there is data before the array and then implement a for loop.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Image belongsTo Property` and `Property hasMany Image`?

Comment: @skywalker but if I do that then I won't have the details for the main_image_id

Comment: Your main image can have column like `main_image` in Images table and can be of type `tinyint` and just set it to 1 and there you have it main image with other images for that `Property`, I think that is the best solution for you.

Comment: @skywalker then how would I display my image as currently I was currently displaying like so <img src='<?php echo '/realestateagencyadministration/img/' . $property['Image']['image'] ?>' style='max-width: 100%;height:150px;;'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer it rather then comment. You will get all the properties and their main image like this (place this in your controller action eg. index()):

```
$properties= $this->Property->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Image' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'main_image' => true
            )
        )
    )
));

$this->set('properties', $properties);
```

and in your view:

```
<img src='<?php echo '/realestateagencyadministration/img/' . $property['Image'][0]['main_image'] ?>' style='max-width: 100%;height:150px;;'>
```

Don't take my for sure on this last one, I am wrinting this out of my head, I think you need [0], but you can easily fix that.

Comment: where would the find be placed in the view or the controller.

Comment: I don't know how I could implement this in Paginator settings

Comment: i was retrieving the properties like so $this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array(
                    $conditionID,
                    $categoryID,
                    $localityID,
                    $serviceTypeID,
                    'Property.price BETWEEN ' . $params['priceFrom'] . ' AND ' . $params['priceTo']),
                'limit' => 15);

Comment: I also tried your code and it returned 2 images still even though one isn't main

Comment: Then just take the `contain` array and add it to your paginator settings array. As for two images, set all other images for that property to have `main_image` 0.

Comment: the other image is main_image 0 and it still loads and I copied you code by copy paste so I can't have a mistake for sure.

Comment: do I have to use containable somewhere?

Comment: Well you are using it with `contain` in your find already. Something must be wrong there, since I have that same code working for me. Did you set up model associations and keys correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49673/discussion-between-enzero-and-skywalker)